# How to form precision-recall curve using one test dataset for my algorithm?

Tags: validation, scikit-learn, nltk, curve, precision-recall

I'm working on knowledge graph, more precisely in natural language processing field. To evaluate the components of my algorithm, it is necessary to be able to classify the good and the poor candidates. For this purpose, we manually classified  pairs in a dataset.

My system returns the relevant pairs according to the implementation logic. now I'm able to calculate :

> ```
> Precision = X
> Recall = Y
> ```

For establishing a complete curve I need the rest of points (X,Y), what should I do?:

> ```
> build another dataset for test ?
> split my dataset ?
> or any other solution ?
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Neither of your proposed two methods. In short, Precision-recall or ROC curve is designed for classifiers with probabilistic output. That is, instead of simply producing a `0` or `1` (in case of binary classification), you need classifiers that can provide a probability in `[0,1]` range. [This](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html) is the function to do it in `sklearn`, note how the 2nd parameter is called `probas_pred`.

To turn this probabilities into concrete class prediction, you can then set a threshold, say at `.5`. Setting such a threshold is problematic however, since you can trade-off precision/recall by varying the threshold, and an arbitrary choice can give false impression of a classifier's performance. To circumvent this, threshold-independent measures like area under ROC or Precision-Recall curve is used. They create thresholds at different intervals, say `0.1,0.2,0.3...0.9`, turn probabilities into binary classes and then compute precision-recall for each such threshold.

Comment: _thanks for the reply_, but this explanation make the concept very fuzzy, in simple way i've test dataset that give me one coordinate **(X,Y)** , (recall, precision) 
how to calculate the rest ?